# how to change textview's drawable color in a custom notification layout?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-theme

I have a custom notification layout with a textview that contains text and drawable. Text's color is automatically set so as to match device's theme.
Since the drawable's color is white, in some devices with light theme it is not visible. I want to find a way to change drawable's color so as to match textview's color (and device's theme as well).

Comment: is your drawable fixed or it changes depending on user profile or something ?

Comment: why don't you use 2 Icons or 3 with different background colors, and depending on the theme you switch them

Comment: @NadirB two problems: 1. how to get what theme is used in notification bar 2. how to set textview's drawable dynamically in a remoteviews?